# Adding and Saving New Contact to AddressBook

Tags: ios, swift, addressbook, addressbookui

I have a problem that I can't quite seem to solve even though I've used resources I've found on Google and on here. I've only started being taught Swift and how to use Xcode about a month ago, hence, I'm very new, and the problem I have is probably very simple to others.

What I'm trying to do is add and save a new contact to the addressbook. I can get from the app to the Contacts app no problem, it's just I can't save the new contact information.

```
import AddressBookUI
import AddressBook

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var contactLink: UIButton!

    @IBAction func contactLink(sender: AnyObject) {
        var viewController: ABNewPersonViewController = ABNewPersonViewController()
        self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Here's the code I'm using that relates to my problem. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowadays, you'd use `ContactsUI` framework. So, in Swift 3, you could do:

```
import ContactsUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, CNContactViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func contactLink(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let controller = CNContactViewController(forNewContact: nil)
        controller.delegate = self
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        self.present(navigationController, animated: true)
    }

    func contactViewController(_ viewController: CNContactViewController, didCompleteWith contact: CNContact?) {
        viewController.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)
    }

}
```

My original answer, using `AddressBookUI` framework in Swift 2 is below.

---

The Swift code is:

```
import AddressBookUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func contactLink(sender: AnyObject) {
        let controller = ABNewPersonViewController()
        controller.newPersonViewDelegate = self
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func newPersonViewController(newPersonView: ABNewPersonViewController!, didCompleteWithNewPerson person: ABRecord!) {
        newPersonView.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```

See the *Prompting the User to Create a New Person Record* section of the [Address Book Programming Guide: User Interaction: Prompting for and Displaying Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW5).